# Laravel, mostrar contenido estatico

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Estoy intentando mostrar siempre el mismo contenido en el footer (Contenido que esta guardado en un campo de la base de dato). El footer tiene que aparecer en todas las paginas de la web.

El problema esque no se como plantearlo:

```
$footer = DB::select('SELECT * FROM generos');
return view('home', ['footer' => $footer]);
```

¿Pasarle la variable `$footer` a todas las view que contengan footer?

¿No hay ninguna manera de crear la variable $footer en un unico sitio y poder pasársela a todas las view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método que plantea Laravel es hacerlo con `View::share()` en el AppServiceProvider:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\[DB, View];

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $footer = DB::select('SELECT * FROM generos');
        View::share('footer', $footer);
    }

    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Más información en la documentación: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#sharing-data-with-all-views

Comment: Y como puedo utilizarlo en la view home?

Comment: Igual que en cualquier otra vista...... llamas el valor `{{ $footer }}` o `{!! $footer !!}` dependiendo si lo quieres "escapado" o no.

Comment: Muchas graciias!!!

Comment: Si esta respuesta y la de la pregunta anterior te sirvieron, puedes marcarlas como aceptadas. Gracias!